# incrementing iterator of std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

Why are lines 7 and 8 bad?? Why it's bad to in-/decrement some iterator?

```
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_multimap<int,int> myumm({{1,3},{3,2},{5,5},{0,9}});
    auto first = myumm.begin();
    auto second = first+1;      // bad
    auto third = --myumm.end(); // bad too
    auto fourth = myumm.end();
}
```

Comment: "bad" is very vague. You should edit your question to clarify it - I'm assuming you're getting compilation errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::unordered_multimap` offers *Forward Iterators.* These are iterators which you can assign, dereference, compare, and increment.

To be able to decrement an iterator (`--it`), you need at least a *Bidirectional Iterator* (such as offered by `std::multimap`).

To be able to add (an arbitrary number) to an iterator (`it + 1`), you need a *Random Access Iterator* (such as offered by `std::vector`). To advance a weaker iterator by more than one place, use `std::advance(it, 42)` (for advancing `it` in place), or `std::next(it, 42)` (which returns the incremented copy and does not modify `it`).

Comment: To be able to decrement an iterator, you also need an lvalue.  The results of `myumm.end()` are not an lvalue, so trying to decrement it is undefined  behavior.  (In practice, if the iterator type supports `--`, it will either work as expected, or you will get a compile time error.  The first if `operator--` is a member function of the iterator, the second if it isn't.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Why would you need an lvalue to increment an iterator of class type? What makes clling `operator--` on a class rvalue undefined?

Comment: You need an lvalue to increment an iterator of pointer type, or an iterator whose increment operators are non-members.  The "undefined" is that the standard doesn't specify how the iterators are to be implemented, so you need to fulfill the requirements for all possible implementations.

Comment: @JamesKanze I stand corrected, C++11 24.2 requires an lvalue for `++` and `--` to work. Thanks for mentioning it, I'm glad I learned something.

Comment: It's more complicated than that.  C++ (even pre-C++11) require lvalues for the built-in `++` and `--` (which are what are used if the iterator is a pointer).  C++ does _not_ require an lvalue for the `this` operand of a member function, even if the member is non-const.  If the operator is a free function, however, its signature must be `Iter& operator++( Iter& i )`.  And once again an lvalue is required.  (And this has always been a legal implementation.)  Finally, C++11 adds the possibility that a member function have a ref-qualifier, so even a member may require an lvalue.

Comment: @JamesKanze The way I read the iterator requirements, for a class `X` to be an iterator, `++r` etc. are defined for `r` of type `X&`.